# Vue Gates Authorization not working as expected when page got Refreshed with refresh button

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm in the process of learning about vue authorization with vue gates.I have a problem with authorization on nuxt using vue gates. the roles authorization(directive) not working properly dispite fetching right roles from api based on authenticated user.when i REFRESH the page the element which is the v-role directive setted got destroyed. so i hoping anybody understand how to solve this problem to tell me what im missing and give me some hint or information to fix this problem.

for api im using laravel, laravel spatie for authorization which is recommended by vue gates its self.

so let me show you my code.

the component:

```
<template>
<div class="container">
  <button v-role="'Admin'">TEST</button> //the directive,this should be displayed but destroyed when page got refreshed. 
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 async asyncData ({ $axios, $gates }) {
   const [roles, permissions] = await Promise.all([
     $axios.$get('/api/admin/roles'),
   ])
  $gates.setRoles(roles)
  console.log(roles)//printing ['Admin'] on console which is correct
 }, 
}
```

the v-role directive not work properly. or did i missing something?
Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `persistent` feature of vue-gates.
Insert`Vue.use(LaravelPermissions, { persistent: true });` in your config file. This also works for nuxt.js.

https://github.com/williamcruzme/vue-gates/issues/15#issuecomment-594624573